# Can I use a single SSLCertificateFile for all my VirtualHosts instead of creating one of it for each VirtualHost?

Tags: apache, ssl, passenger, wildcard, virtualhost

I have many Apache VirtualHosts for each of which I use a dedicated SSLCertificateFile.

This is an configuration example of a VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

     ServerName subdomain.domain.localhost

     DocumentRoot "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/users/public"
     RackEnv development

   <Directory "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/users/publ`enter code here`ic">
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
   </Directory>

    # SSL Configuration
    SSLEngine on

    #Self Signed certificates
    SSLCertificateFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl/ca.crt

</VirtualHost>
```

Since I am maintaining more Ruby on Rails applications using [Passenger Preference Pane](http://www.modrails.com/), this is a part of the apache2 *httpd.conf* file:

```
<IfModule passenger_module>
  NameVirtualHost *:80
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName _default_
  </VirtualHost>
  Include /private/etc/apache2/passenger_pane_vhosts/*.conf
</IfModule>
```

**Can I use a single SSLCertificateFile for all my VirtualHosts (I have heard of wildcards) instead of creating one of it for each VirtualHost?** If so, how can I change the files listed above?

Comment: http://playnice.ly/blog/2011/01/03/multi-domain-ucc-ssl-certificates-on-nginx-with-1-ip-address/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have two things to solve; how to get a cert (pub/priv) that works for all your hosts -and then next - how to arrange the vHosts and the use of strategic includes. (I am ignoring the SNI option here - do read up on that though).

For the first - you roughly have threee options - a wildcard cert (i.e. *.foo.bar.com), a cert with multiple CN's in the DN (E.g. "CN=foo.com, CN=bar.com, L=London..") or a cert with 1 or more Subject Alternative Names containing DNS names (http://playnice.ly/blog/2011/01/03/multi-domain-ucc-ssl-certificates-on-nginx-with-1-ip-address/). The latter two are good when you have just a handful of vhosts (but they can have any name; so no wildcard limits). While the wildcard is your only option when you have 10's to 100's of domains - but the downside is that they have to have a similar leaf name (though you'd be surprised how 'easy' is to get a *.com issued by accident).

Once you have one of these beass - simply include it on server level.

So next up is how to splice things from thereon - what you need here is the same setup as for an SNI host (see docs or http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI).

To make your live easy - you could consider using 'include' snippets - or, worst case, generate the config with a small shell script (or go all out - you can include perl and the output it generates 'virtually' on the fly!).

Dw.

Comment: +1, I'll just add something about SNI,note that on the browser support there's no IE6 and ni IE7-XP. So use SNI with care if you either want to use it.

Comment: Aye - but above does not rely on SNI - it is just the same config struct.

Comment: Finally I can get a single certificate for all subdomains: I can access https: //subdomain.domain.localhost. Now, anyway, I can not access anymore http: //subdomain.domain.localhost!!! Why? P.S.: on my Mac Os, accessing the "http: version", I get a default page "Your website." (files related to the subdomain are in the /Users/<my_user_name>/Sites folder)

Comment: You'll need to check your error log (log level debug) - and run httpd from the command line with the -S flag to see how you vhosts are actually matched. I suspect you have some accidental overlap or a fallback to * or default in the wrong order.

Comment: How does the last thing work exactly?
`Include /home/bla/my_vhost_config.cgi`? When the contents change, do you need to reload apache?

Comment: Yes - when the content of your config file changes - you need to inform the daemon. This is best done with a 'graceful' restart - as this ensures than no requests are lost or interrupted.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

path="$HOME/Desktop"
days=""

echo -ne "Hello. You must be hoping to create a SSL/TLS security certificate (and key).\n\nBy default, this key will be self-signed. However, you can decide instead to\ncreate an un-signed certificate request (.pem) file to be signed by a\nrecognized certificate authority.\n\nPlease choose from the following options.\n\n s: create a self-signed certificate .crt file (default)\n u: create an un-signed certificate request .pem file\n q: quit\n> "
read go

if [ "$go" = "u" ]; then

  echo -ne "What is your country code?\n> "
  read c
  echo -ne "What is your state/province?\n> "
  read st
  echo -ne "What is your city?\n> "
  read l
  echo -ne "What is your organization name?\n> "
  read o

elif [ "$go" = "q" ]; then

  echo -e "\nHave a nice day."
  exit 0

fi

echo -ne "What is your domain name?\n> "
read domain

if [ -z "$domain" ]; then
  echo "No domain was given."
  exit 0
fi

echo -ne "What is the path where your certificate files should be saved?\n> "
read path
echo -ne "For how many days will your certificate be valid?\n> "
read days

if [ -z "$path" ]; then path="."; fi
if [ -z "$c" ]; then c="US"; fi
if [ -z "$st" ]; then st="Arizona"; fi
if [ -z "$l" ]; then l="Phoenix"; fi
if [ -z "$o" ]; then o="PLUG"; fi
if [ -z "$days" ]; then days="365"; fi

if [ -d "$path" ]; then
  echo -ne "\nCreating your certificate ..."
  if [ "$go" = "u" ]; then
    (echo -e "oid_section = new_oids\n[ new_oids ]\n[ req ]\ndefault_days = $days\ndefault_keyfile = $path/$domain.key\ndistinguished_name = req_distinguished_name\nencrypt_key = no\nstring_mask = nombstr\nreq_extensions = v3_req\n[ req_distinguished_name ]\ncommonName = Common Name (eg, YOUR name)\ncommonName_default = $domain\ncommonName_max = 64\n[ v3_req ]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:$domain,DNS:*.$domain" > deleteme.cfg) &> /dev/null;
    (openssl req -batch -config deleteme.cfg -newkey rsa:2048 -out $path/$domain.pem) &> /dev/null;
    (rm deleteme.cfg) &> /dev/null;
  else
    (echo -e "subjectAltName=DNS:$domain,DNS:*.$domain" > deleteme.cfg) &> /dev/null;
    (openssl genrsa -out $path/$domain.key 2048) &> /dev/null;
    (openssl req -new -key $path/$domain.key -subj "/C=$c/ST=$st/L=$l/O=$o/CN=$domain" -out deleteme.csr) &> /dev/null;
    (openssl x509 -req -in deleteme.csr -signkey $path/$domain.key -days $days -text -extfile deleteme.cfg -out $path/$domain.crt) &> /dev/null;
    (rm deleteme.cfg deleteme.csr) &> /dev/null;
  fi
  (chmod 400 $path/$domain.key) &> /dev/null;
  echo " done."
else
  echo "No such directory exists."
fi

echo -e "\nHave a nice day."
```

It's a bash script - so you'd save it to a file (name it whatever) on your BSD/Linux/Mac/UNIX/etc. computer, wherever you want. Then you'd open up a terminal and do something like this:

```
$ cd wherever
$ chmod +x whatever
$ ./whatever
```

And then you'd follow the instructions. It'll say "do you want a self signed certificate or a certificate request that somebody else can sign?", and then it'll say "what's your domain name?" and "when should this expire?", and so forth.

When it's done, you'll have two files. You'll have a .key file that is write-protected and that contains your private key. And you'll have a .crt file that contains the self-signed certificate, or a .pem file that contains the un-signed certificate request. The script will let you specify where you want the files saved.

If you are planning to use a self-signed certificate, you're done. Go ahead and setup your virtualhost on your server (as you seem to have done already). If you are planning to use a third-party signing authority (i.e., Verisign, etc.), then you'll have to send your .pem file to them and they will respond by sending you a signed .crt file.

Comment: Nice script. I didn't realise `req` had a `-batch` option.